# How does a Ring of Counterspells work against an area-of-effect (AOE) spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

A person is wearing a [Ring of Counterspells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-counterspells) which is storing a [Fireball](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fireball) spell.  When this person is in the AOE of a fireball is the entire fireball countered?  Do they negate it just for their square?  Is there some other outcome?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Nothing happens.**

A *ring of counterspells* only triggers when the wearer is the target of the same spell it stores. Since area-effect spells target a location, not a creature, the *ring* can't be triggered by merely being in the AoE of a *fireball*. Being merely caught in the blast area isn't enough to activate the spell-countering effect.

The ring might counter a fireball that directly impacted you, at the GM's discretion. *Fireball* is a bit of an odd-ball spell for an area-effect spell, since it can "impact" something between the caster and the target location:

> [if the glowing, pea-sized bead] impacts upon a material body or solid barrier prior to attaining the prescribed range, [it] blossoms into the fireball at that point

A GM could rule that this is enough interaction between the wearer of the *ring* and the *fireball* to count as having the spell being cast directly "upon" the wearer – even though *fireball* doesn't have a creature target – that the ring would trigger.

Comment: The ring doesn't technically use that particular phrasing, though; the trigger is "should that spell ever be cast upon the wearer".  Contrast with the phrasing of [spell turning](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/spellTurning.htm), which does require that you be the target of the spell.  And you could certainly ready an action to counterspell *fireball*.  So, I'd interpret the phrase "cast upon" as being just the regular English usage, and not another way of saying "targeted by".

Comment: @starwed I know. But that wording is system-equivalent to being the target of the spell. Fireball isn't cast upon a creature, it's cast upon a point in space. There's a reason that the *ring* is confusing when you try to apply it to AoE spells: it doesn't interact with them, so the designers didn't bother to explain how much it counters a spell that it doesn't interact with.

Comment: I disagree.  There isn't actually any confusion; the fireball is *counterspelled*, just like the ring's name suggests.  If they meant only targeted spells, they would have said so.  Again, contrast with the nature of *spell turning* -- turning AoE spells would be confusing, since they can't be redirected to target the original caster.  Such an issue does not exist with counterspelling.

Comment: Oh, this is actually brought up in the official FAQ, but the answer is somewhat anti-helpful.  See my posted answer.

Comment: @starwed That FAQ answer says pretty much exactly what my answer says. Nothing happens, unless you're the target of the spell. *Quod erat demonstrandum*.

Comment: @starwed I expanded the answer to deal with being hit point-blank by the fireball – it follows from the core rules about targetting even without the FAQ answer. I didn't feel it necessary to include before because the question is asking about being caught in the blast, not aimed at with a fireball.

Answer (score 4):

This is in the official 3.5 FAQ, but honestly the answer is somewhat hard to generalize from.  Pathfinder does rule differently on some issues, of course.

> **Can a ring of counterspells counter a fireball spell or other area effect if the wearer is in the affected area?**
>
> The ring of counterspells counters spells that are cast on you only, not necessarily a spell that affects you. So if you were the target of a fireball, then the ring would counter it; however, if you were just standing too close to the intended target, you would be affected normally and the ring of counterspells would not come into play.

I would personally interpret the ring as working the same way a readied action to counterspell would work -- that anytime you'd be affected by the spell, the ring would counterspell it for you.  This is not 100% clear from the rules, and is specifically contrary to the FAQ answer.  (Which was 3.5 in any case.)

Comment: I disagree that the ring should work as a readied action to counterspell. I think that in this instance the RAW is best, and that AoE spells get under the ring's defenses.

Comment: Absent the (3.5) FAQ, that's not the rules as written.  The phrase "cast upon" is not a defined game term, so there is legitimate ambiguity on whether it means "targeted" or just "affected by".  I am using the idea of a readied counterspell as an analogy, to suggest *why* I would infer a particular meaning.

Comment: I understand, but I disagree that your inference makes for the best game, and the FAQ supports my opinion, so I'm erring on the "no effect" side.